# Creating a Sorting Machine (Finite State Machine)

Tags: state-machines

So here is my task:

Design a sorting machine. The idea!is to design a two-port read two-port write register
file with k registers. The data are stored in registers using some input switches (address
and data are specified by switches). Then there are two counters, C1 and C2. A four
state machine sorts the numbers as follows.

Load the registers with initial values. Start the machine in state S0.

State S0:
C1 is initialized to 0. Go to state S1.

State S1:
C2 is initialized to C1 +1. (Need add 1 circuit). Go to State S2.

State S2:
Read two registers from two addresses specified by C1 and C2.
Call them D1 and D2.
Feed D1 and D2 into a maximizer/minimizer circuit.
It yields MAX and MIN on two ports.
At clock edge
MAX is written into register C1 and MIN is written into register C2.
(This swaps max and min).

If C1 = k-2 then Go to state S3
Else if C2 = k-1 then increment C1 and Go to State S1
Else increment C2 and Go to State S2

State S3:
Registers are displayed on 7-segment displays.
Done.

This is what I have come up with so far:

[image]

When zi and zj are both 1, the circuit is supposed to stop I guess... I just don't even know what I am supposed to do with them as far as connecting them to anything. Then I have no idea what to do with BltA output and don't know where you even get Bout mux input. I also don't know where Ain and Bin enables are coming from.

so would really love it if someone could help me out with this :P.

P.S. I basically copied a diagram from a textbook. Ours is supposed to be "slightly different" but I honestly have absolutely no idea what I am doing. We were taught how to make things like this and all the textbook does is show us an ASM then shows the circuit with no explanation. So yeah... it sucks. Basically I have no idea how you go from a vague ASM chart to a datapath/control circuit.

Comment: If it's true that you have "absolutely no idea what I'm doing" then I suggest that you drop the class and change majors immediately. If you do have some idea, then show us some effort on your part. Draw a proper schematic, write some code, run some simulations. Try to do the design yourself, and come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: Well it is the end of the semester and I have an A in the class... So... Screw you? Our professor has been rushing content now to get it all in and throws this project at us even though he has never prepared us to actually tackle something like this. So forgive me if I am lost. And as I said, the textbook explains NOTHING about what is going on.

Comment: My questions were based on the assignment specs and diagram, what are possible uses/origins for the variables I mentioned in original post. Another issue is the textbook didn't even mention over half of the variables so again, I don't know where they are coming from or where they are going.

Comment: You've now asked the same question three times (first two times were closed).  You've got all sorts of variables and other terms here that you haven't explained: k, zi, zj, BltA, Bout, Bin etc.  I understand from your previous comment your textbook doesn't mention some of them, but how are we supposed to know what they are?  We're not psychics.

Answer (score 2):

I have a particular interest in hardware sorting, so I'm going to take a crack at this, despite the issues with the question.

In very general terms, for any in-place sorting algorithm, you're going to need to be able to read two values out of the RAM (register file), compare them, and if they're in the wrong order, write them back in the opposite locations from where they were read.

The first step is to create a datapath that can do those steps.

- Most FPGAs have blocks of static RAM (BRAM) that have dual ports, which makes that part easy. You feed one address to each port, and you get the two data values you need to compare at the data outputs.
- The next part is to create a module that compares the two values and produces a logical signal that's true if they need to be swapped. This usually takes the form of a binary subtractor with a little logic on the sign and carry bits of the result to determine A>B, A≥B, A<B or A≤B, whichever you need.
- Finally, if the swap is needed, you need to route the two data outputs from the BRAM back to the data inputs, but on the opposite ports. Then, when you assert the write enable on each port, it gets the value from the other port.

The second step is to identify the connections between the control logic and the datapath.

- Two addresses, one for each port of the BRAM.
- The status signal from the compare module.
- A write enable that goes to both ports of the BRAM.

The control logic will also need some sort of "start" input signal and a "done" output signal.

It can be a bit of a toss-up as to whether you consider the address generation logic to be part of the datapath or the control logic. It depends on what kind of sort algorithm you want to implement. If addressing is strictly sequential, you might use binary up/down counters and make them part of the datapath. Then, their control inputs (and underflow/overflow status) would become additional connections from/to the control logic.

The third step is to start drawing a timing diagram that shows what changes when, for both the datapath and the control signals. When is data/status valid, and when do the control outputs (addresses and write enables) need to be stable and when can they change?

The fourth step is to come up with a state machine definition that meets the requirements derived in the previous step. Finally, you then pick an appropriate implementation technology for the state machine, such as one-hot, random logic, or microcoded.

Does any of this help? Do you have any *specific* questions on any part?

From your question, I get the impression that you've gotten ahead of yourself by thinking about the state machine before you have a solid idea of what it is that it needs to control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm... I think I am kind of coming along with this, I scrapped that original design and started from scratch. But now I am having an issue of how do you handle your circuit moving states on its own? Like if A < B when they are compared, then go to state where A is put into register 1 then go to next state where B is put into register 2. I don't get how you make it so it operates like that on its own. Simple FSM's were easy, # states = # flip flops, and you made state table, found inputs, etc. This datapath crap though with its slew of random states. I don't get it.